# Passive FTP port range, can I dedicate a port (range) per FTP user or folder in IIS?

Tags: iis, ftp, port, windows-server-2016

I'm using IIS (10) on Server 2016 for my FTP site. I have a list of IIS users that have rights to their own subfolder under my FTP site. 
I have passive FTP configured to use a portrange of a 100 ports. I have a about 50 users so 100 ports is not that for fetched I would think.

However I'm wondering if I can configure a port per user or per subfolder of the site so that some of my clients don't have to open 100 ports outbound to support my site's entire port range.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However I'm wondering if I can configure a port per user or per
>   subfolder of the site so that some of my clients don't have to open
>   100 ports outbound to support my site's entire port range.

As far as I know, I think it is **not** possible, because data channel port range set for this IIS server, we can't set port range for each subfolder.